# Simulated low memory warning not working

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have a `UIWebView` in a `UIViewController`. I am trying to push this view controller to an existing `UINavigationController`, that has another view controller which also has a `UIWebView` in it. After pushing the first view controller I try to simulate a memory warning, and then I hit "back" to go to the previous view controller, but now this webview is empty/blank. Any idea on how to go around this?

This is only happening on the iPad 1, running iOS 5.

Comment: Sounds like its working just fine to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under a low memory condition under iOS 5.x or earlier, a view controller's view may be unloaded. Then when it needs to be loaded again, the view controller's `viewDidLoad` will be called after the view is put back in place. Make sure you are doing the right things in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` to handle this case.

Comment: I thought viewDidUnload is not getting caled again in iOS 5

Comment: `viewDidUnload` is deprecated and no longer called as of iOS 6.0. But it is still called in iOS 5.x and earlier.

Comment: so viewDidUnload is getting called, but what can I do in this case?

Comment: `viewDidUnload` can be used to clear up memory. But the solution to your problem is in `viewDidLoad`. This will get called again when your view reloads.