# issue with view in memory warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulated low memory warning not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106687/simulated-low-memory-warning-not-working)

So I have a UIViewController with a webview in it. I tried pushing another viewcontroller into the nav controller and then simulate a memory warning and then go back. Now the view with the webview is purely blank. I tried adding a view and changing the background color to this code and it didn't add it after the memory warning. I tried calling setNeedsLayout and setNeedsDisplay and it didn't help either. It's as if the view is not there. So I double checked the view frame and it is:

```
<UIView: 0x8aebd70; frame = (0 0; 768 960); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x8ae2830>>
```

any idea why?

Comment: repost of [Simulated low memory warning not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106687/simulated-low-memory-warning-not-working). Please edit your earlier question to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the complete HTML page then store it in local cache and then tell the webview load it. So whenever the webview receive mem warning it will unload the content it memory and when you go back it will load HTML in cache

Comment: how do I store the complete html page in a local cache?

Comment: Take a look at ASIHTTPRequest

Answer (score 0):

It's normal. Before iOS6 memory warning remove the root view from not visible view controllers, from iOS6 it removes just the backing store of non visible views owned by view controllers. So everything depends on where you tell the webview to load the html page. I will suggest you to use `-viewWillAppear`.